# None of the linux programs work except 'cd'

Tags: fedora, kernel, libraries, glibc

Before stating the question, here's what I did and observed before the problem started:

1. On a fedora 18 Xfce, I tried compiling 3.6.10 kernel with a cdv driver,
2. After many attempts, it finally compiled without error, so I went ahead with `make modules_install`, and `make install`.
3. Then I had to install couple of binaries from a few tarballs. Everything seemed fine till this moment. I could use `firefox`, `vi` in terminal, `yum`, `rpm` etc. commands.
4. I installed binaries from few tarballs using `tar xvf` and a few files from these tarballs were moved to directories like `/usr`, `/usr/lib`. Even after this point, I remember using `vi` and `rpm`.
5. Then finally I installed the last tarball using same `tar xvf` and it transferred few files to `/lib`, `/lib/firmware` etc.

After the 5th step above, without doing anything else, I just tried opening one file using `vi` command and got following error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/vi /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I tried opening Firefox for solution, but it did not open. Fired few more commands from terminal but all the commands gave similar error. I checked few solutions that suggest installing glibc but neither `yum` works nor `rpm`. What might have gone wrong? How can it be fixed now when no command except `cd` is working, not even `ls`?

Meanwhile the only other hiccup that happened was that I had for kill Firefox somewhere in between since the machine wasn't responding very well and some plugin in it was eating up resources.

Comment: After some looking into the file system using already running file browser, I found ld-linux.so.2 file in /usr/lib, just copied /usr/lib/ld-linux.so.2 and /usr/lib/ld-2.16.so files to /lib. And viola! the problem resolved, all the commands are back.

I am not really sure what happened here, but my /lib was empty except for the files put up by the 'tar xvf'. I am yet to reboot and see what happens. But for now it is solved. Can anyone help me understand why /lib became empty or was it already so and what is the solution to avoid it?

Comment: First , Fedora 18 is now at end of life, so support is limited. Your problem is that you are not using the package manager to install and thus are deleting or over writing files. This is bad practice. See - https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Package_management_system

Comment: The reason I am doing this is to get the cedartrail powervr drivers working on a newer kernel. Intel has officially given a set of instructions but it refers to 3.1 kernel version. So for porting the driver to later kernel, I choose a mid-way kernel and followed the instructions. After many changes, the driver code is made suitable for 3.6.10 and compiles fine without any warnings. Problem is with the installation instructions given in the intel document where it says using make install for the kernel and few more tar archives for other libraries.

Comment: I am not sure if rpm of equivalent libraries from intel are available. I also suspect using vanilla kernel on fedora system may not be a good idea and also there must be something missing in the make configurations that does not load /lib properly. After rebooting, I am not getting a blank screen with the installed kernel and if I remove the line 'video=lvds-1:d' it takes me to emergency mode with error messages like 'Failed to start Load kernel modules' and 'failed to initialize storage subsystem'.

Comment: Wow, let this be a lesson to all who would blindly untar executables and libraries into OS critical directories.  This is a recipe to bork your system.

Comment: @rickhg12hs well thats true but as said, its a development and test system, so don't really mind it but still want to know internals better. Besides intel should really step up to fix this and stop giving specific binaries for specific versions, at least should release the sources so we can recompile and repackage them for any system. Anyway, learned a lot through this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A lot depends on what **exactly** you unpacked into your system. Generally, using `tar` to install things on a system with package management is a Bad Idea (TM). My guess would be you used a tarball for a different distribution or it didn't properly create some symbolic links. In other words, I suppose the root of the problem might be the [`/usr` - `/` merge](https://lwn.net/Articles/477467/). But lots of other things could have gone wrong.

Comment: Indeed. Some time with `rpm -V` is probably warranted.

Answer (score 5):

`/lib/ld-linux.so.2` is the [dynamic loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_%28computing%29#Dynamic_linkers) for dynamically-linked executables, which is almost all of them. Specifically, `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` is the standard path for the dynamic loader on i386 (32-bit) systems. This file must exist and be valid (it can be a symbolic link), otherwise almost no program will be able to start (programs that are already running, such as your shell, aren't affected).

Try to recreate the dynamic loader. Hopefully you have it somewhere already, but in a wrong location. Look for it. Note that you can use `echo *` to list the contents of the current directory.

If you find the dynamic loader somewhere, you can use it to create a symbolic link in the right location. Say you find that `/lib32/ld-linux.so.2` looks valid, then you can run

```
/lib32/ld-linux.so.2 ln -s /lib32/ld-linux.so.2 /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

Plausible directories are `/lib`, `/lib32`, `/usr/lib`, `/usr/lib32`. Plausible names have the form `ld-*.so`.

Your system may still be broken in other ways but at least you'll be able to keep going. Note that you should never copy files manually inside `/lib` or `/usr`, except under `/lib/modules` and `/usr/local`.

Comment: Thanks. Almost everything came up after linking /usr/lib with /lib.  But then, had to remove all the binary files installed through tarball and also reinstall few equivalent packages that provide similar libraries to get the system log in to graphical mode. Finally this system is up and running without problem, except that it still does not support the particular driver that I was trying to compile. Turns out that some of that driver depends on proprietary technology sources for which are not yet released by intel. PowerVR Graphics to be specific.

Answer (score 2):

The reason `cd` works is simply because it is an internal command of `bash` and not an external program. Other built-in commands like `echo` should work as well.

That at least explains why that works, but doesn't solve the problem of having trashed your external command setup. For that I would go for restoring from backup after booting from rescue partition (or CD if you don't have that).

Answer (score 0):

When you compiled are you included the elf and out file format?
And compat32?
When you compile ensure all "standard" options of the standard kernel are included
best way is

```
cd /usr/src/linux(must point to your new sources)
zcat /proc/config.gz > .config
make clean
make oldconfig
#answer only if sure and use a lot the ?
make,make install
etc etc
```

Of course before compiling kernel a backup is not a bad idea
Excuse my english a little bad